# Operations on two Lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list

let me start with some background.

Let's say I have this list:

```
interactions = [ ['O1', 'O3'],
               ['O2', 'O5'],
               ['O8', 'O10']
               ['P3', 'P5'],
               ['P2', 'P19'],
               ['P1', 'P6'] ]
```

Each entry in the list (eg: `O1, O3`) is an interaction between two entities (although everything we're dealing with here are Strings). There are many different entities in the list.

We also have the following list:

```
similar = ['O1', 'P23'],
          ['O3', 'P50'],
          ['P2', 'O40'],
          ['P19', 'O22']
```

In which each entry is a relationship of similarity between two **different** entities.

So **O1** is similar to **P23** and **O3** is similar to **P50** AND [O1, O3] interact thus the interaction ['P23', 'P50'] is a transformed interaction.

Likewise, **P2** is similar to **O40** and **P19** is similar to **O22** AND [P2, P19] interact thus the interaction ['O40', 'O22'] is a transformed interaction.

The transformed interactions will always be from the same type, eg: [PX, PX] or [OX, OX].

### Code

So I wrote the following code to generate these relationship transfers:

```
from collections import defaultdict

interactions = [ ['O1', 'O3'],
                 ['O2', 'O5'],
                 ['O8', 'O10']
                 ['P3', 'P5'],
                 ['P2', 'P19'],
                 ['P1', 'P6'] ]

similar = [ ['O1', 'H33'],
            ['O6', 'O9'],
            ['O4', 'H1'],
            ['O2', 'H12'] ]

def list_of_lists_to_dict(list_of_lists):
  d = defaultdict(list)
  for sublist in list_of_lists:
    d[sublist[0]].append(sublist[1])
    d[sublist[1]].append(sublist[0])
  return d

interactions_dict = list_of_lists_to_dict(interactions)
similar_dict = list_of_lists_to_dict(similar)


for key, values in interactions_dict.items():
  print "{0} interacts with: {1}".format(key, ', '.join(values))
    if key in similar_dict:
      print " {0} is similar to: {1}".format(key, ', '.join(similar_dict[key]))
      forward = True
  for value in values:
    if value in similar_dict:
      print " {0} is similar to: {1}".format(value, ', '.join(similar_dict[value]))
      reverse = True
      if forward and reverse:
        print "     thus [{0}, {1}] interact!".format(', '.join(similar_dict[key]), 
         ',  '.join(similar_dict[value]))
  forward = reverse = False
```

My attempt does generate the correct output, but it also generated unwanted output. For example, sometimes it will generate output between different types of entities: `O1, P1`, and between the exact same entities: `O1, O1`. It also also outputs duplicate results in different forms, eg: `O1, P1`, `P1, O1` - both mean the same thing so we only want this entry once. All of this is unwanted behaviour.

So my question is, how can I restructure my attempt to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `set` not `list`?  Its sometimes easier to collapse duplicates than to try and cull them.

Comment: Where is this question from? it's almost an exact clone of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304400/implementing-this-algorithm-on-lists-python?rq=1) one...

Comment: Seems like `Jake D` got a brand new profile on SO today :) ;)

Comment: IMO using this with list of lists is the wrong way. Learn about Classes and OOP. http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/OOP.shtml

Comment: It would help if you said "Given x & y " I would like the following output "Output ... "; then go on to explain the algorithm. You code doesn't run anyway. Also show what you got and what you expected.

Comment: @RohitJain, calm down Sherlock. Yes, that other post is mine. I couldn't remember my login details so I made a new account last night. I'd rather not share my name on the Internet, hence the different names on the accounts. I had only noticed the described unwanted behaviour when applying the advice from the previous thread to a larger data set; hence this post.

Comment: @JasonJ.. Why do you think I'm not calm? And who is this Sherlock?

Comment: @sotapme, So I guess the algorithm for this would be:

for every unique entity A in the in fields [0] and [1] in list similar,
fetch a list B of interactions from the list interactions.
check for entries in similar where A is similar to some object A', and B is similar to some object B'.
map the interaction between A' and B'.

Comment: Is your similarity relation transitive? That is, if A is similar to B, and B is similar to C, is A also similar to C? And is it symmetric? If A is similar to B, is B also similar to A?

Comment: @GarethRees, No, it is neither transitive nor symmetric.

Comment: Try to ask the question without so much background info/noise.

Answer (score 1):

If the similarity relationship is neither symmetric nor transitive:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import product

# entity -> similar entities
d = defaultdict(list) # use `set` if `similar` has duplicate entries
for k, v in similar:
    d[k].append(v)

for a, b in interactions:
    for x, y in product(d[a], d[b]): 
       # a, b interact; a is similar to x, b is similar to y
       #note: filter undesired x, y interactions here
       print x, y # transformed interaction
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the help! One thing though, this still produces entries where the entities are of different type (`P01, X01`). Is your comment in the last for loop referring to this behaviour? I wasn't sure if you meant to filter out these entries or it was implicit through this method of looping. Of course I will filter out the other result such as when x == y. Cheers!

Comment: @JasonJ: if the types are determined by the first character then to enforce the same type and exclude the exact same entries: `if x[0] == y[0] and x != y: print x, y`

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case. If It were it would make my whole life a lot easier. It's OK though, I'll manage it. Thanks for the help though mate! :)

Comment: @Jason: What do you mean by 'that is not the case' ? What is not covered in the solution? It seems to me that it has provided solution for all the constraints that you have posted. If not, you should explain what is your problem.

Comment: @Thava: I was referring to `if the types are determined by the first character...`.

Answer (score 1):

I have some recommendations for the overall algorithm:

- Keep a dictionary for all the similarity relationships, for example O1:P23 and P23:O1 can both be in the dictionary.
- Before finding a transformation, check to make sure that both parts of the interaction can be transformed, for example O1 and O3 must both be keys in the dictionary
- This should prevent any transformation being listed as an O and a P together, which you said was unwanted output.
- You could also keep a dictionary of results to check for duplicates if you think this will be a problem.

Some of these problems are addressed by J.F. Sebastian's answer, but I think you should pay attention to how the original dictionary is constructed, that will make it so much easier to come up with results that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If u convert your lists to dictionary, then you can easily match keys of the dictionaries and retrieve values at those keys.